# Django: NOT NULL constraint failed: crf_heu.date_id

Tags: python, django, constraints

I have a very simple models but fail to resolve an error linked to constraint

I have 2 models: Jours and Heures linked with a OneToMany relationship (one Jours instance can have multiples Heures instances)

I have a form to add records in Heures but have an error I did not understand:

> NOT NULL constraint failed: crf_heu.date_id

**models.py**

```
class Jours(models.Model):

    _safedelete_policy = SOFT_DELETE_CASCADE
    jou_ide = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    jou_dat = models.DateField("Date du pointage", null=True, blank=True)
    log = HistoricalRecords()

    class Meta:

        db_table = 'crf_jou'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Dates'
        ordering = ['jou_ide']

    def __str__(self):

        return f"{self.jou_dat}"

class Heures(models.Model):

    _safedelete_policy = SOFT_DELETE_CASCADE
    heu_ide = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    date = models.ForeignKey(Jours, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    heu_dat = models.TimeField("Heure du pointage", null=True, blank=True,auto_now_add=True)
    heu_cod = models.IntegerField("Code employé", null=True, blank=True)    
    heu_com = models.CharField("Commentaires", max_length = 150, null=True, blank=True)
    log = HistoricalRecords()

    class Meta:

        db_table = 'crf_heu'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Heures'
        ordering = ['heu_ide']

    def __str__(self):

        return f"{self.heu_dat}"
```

**views.py**

```
@login_required
def index(request):

    if request.method == "POST":
        form = HeuresForm(request, data=request.POST or None)
        if form.is_valid():
            heu_cod = form.cleaned_data['heu_cod'],
            heu_com = form.cleaned_data['heu_com'],
            date_id = Jours.objects.get(jou_dat = datetime.date.today()).jou_dat
            form.save()

            return redirect('home')

    else:
        form = HeuresForm(request)

    return render(request, 'pointage/index.html', {'form': form})
```

**forms.py**

```
class HeuresForm(forms.ModelForm):

    # surcharge méthode constructeur (__init__) pour avoir accès aux variables de sessions
    # https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3778148/django-form-validation-including-the-use-of-session-data
    def __init__(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.request = request
        super(HeuresForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    class Meta:
        model = Heures
        fields = ('heu_cod','heu_com',)

    heu_dat= forms.CharField(label ='Heure du pointage', widget=forms.TimeInput(),initial = datetime.datetime.now,)
    heu_cod = forms.CharField(label ='Code employé', widget=forms.PasswordInput())
    heu_com = forms.CharField(label ='Commentaires', widget=forms.TextInput())
```

Comment: You didn't specified here `date = models.ForeignKey(Jours, on_delete = models.CASCADE)` in `crf_heu` table that field could be `NULL` and in your form you haven't added this field.

Comment: but It can not be null as it is the Foreign Key

Comment: It [do can](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.SET_NULL) in Django

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't allowed `You didn't specified here date = models.ForeignKey(Jours, on_delete = models.CASCADE)` to be null, you need or to allow that, or to add this field on a form:

```
class HeuresForm(forms.ModelForm):

    def __init__(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.request = request
        super(HeuresForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    gender = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Heures.objects.all(),
                                    to_field_name = 'date',
                                    empty_label="Select heures")
    class Meta:
        model = Heures
        fields = ('heu_cod', 'heu_com', 'gender)

    heu_dat= forms.CharField(label ='Heure du pointage', widget=forms.TimeInput(),initial = datetime.datetime.now,)
    heu_cod = forms.CharField(label ='Code employé', widget=forms.PasswordInput())
    heu_com = forms.CharField(label ='Commentaires', widget=forms.TextInput())
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to change "jou_ide" to id which is AutoField on Jours. After that, it may require "null=True" to date column from Heures model.

Comment: I have add null=True: date = models.ForeignKey(Jours, on_delete = models.CASCADE, null=True) which resolve error for sure but date stay empty (Null) when I registered a Jours instance